# HaProxy and Windows Auth

Tags: authentication, haproxy, ntlm

Can I get HaProxy to forward windows auth credentials onto IIS?
I have searched for a day and cannot find much information out there.

Comment: How is the authentication captured by the webserver?  HTTP Basic Auth?

Comment: Hey @Kyle, At the moment just windows authentication is turned on, not basic.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "windows authentication" ? Is it NTLM auth over HTTP ? It's not very clear from your question. If it's NTLM auth, you need haproxy to work in tunnel mode because NTLM auth is not HTTP-compliant and authenticates the *connection* instead of the *request*. So you want haproxy to forward all traffic from the same connection to the same server. Using NTLM auth over proxies is dangerous BTW because you never know if proxies will multiplex connections or not, which could result in having multiple users browsing with the same account (haproxy does not do this right now).

Comment: well Integrated Windows authentication, formerly called NTLM. Thanks for the pointer on tunnel mode, not come across this but will check the docs.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem.  HAProxy by default runs with `option http-tunnel` unless you specify something like `option httpclose`.  I was trying something like this:

```
defaults
    option httpclose
    ...

backend http
    no option httpclose
    server devweb01 10.10.10.10:80 check
```

But this did not work.  When I removed `option httpclose` from the `defaults` section, it worked.  I also tried adding `option http-tunnel` inside my backend but this had no effect.